# PyTorch: `torch.chunk` source code Github location

Tags: python, github, pytorch

I can’t seem to find the source code for torch.chunk in PyTorch’s Github page or in the documentation.

Anyone knows where this is in PyTorch’s Github page?

Comment: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/datasets/chunk.h

Comment: Many thanks @IainShelvington. So many subfolders just to get to `chunk`!

Comment: Apparently someone from PyTorch forum said the above link you have given is for the Chunk data reader and not `torch.chunk`. `Torch.chunk` code is in: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/aten/src/ATen/native/TensorShape.cpp#L496

Comment: @Leockl Good point. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the main GitHub project https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch

Then type in this page the keyboard shortcut <kbd>t</kbd>: you will enter the file finder mode ([introduced in 2011](https://github.blog/2011-02-10-introducing-the-file-finder/)). (https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/find/master)

Type "`chunk.h`": the first result will be your file.

[image: chunk]

If the file is not the right one (header but not source), then you need a search:

https://github.com/search?q=%22chunk%22+%22const+Tensor%22+repo%3Apytorch%2Fpytorch+extension%3Acpp+language%3AC%2B%2B+language%3AC%2B%2B&type=Code

Search for `chunk` and "`const Tensor`" helps to refine rapidly the search results to [`TensorShape.cpp#chunk()`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/91d87292a6fb3c6676e0b967cd6c8222d3fd820b/aten/src/ATen/native/TensorShape.cpp#L496), as noted in the comment.